# 32-bit Eclipse problem

Tags: eclipse

I have 64-bit Ubuntu and Eclipse 64-bit for an older project. In 32-bit I tried to run it, but it doesn't work (swt)... so I decided to download a tarball of Eclipse 32-bit (with JVM 32-bit integrated). All fine, but so far I cannot seem to run it. Do you have any ideas?

```
  4 drwxrwsr-x  9 wouter wouter   4096 Feb 16  2012 .
  4 drwxr-xr-x  6 wouter wouter   4096 Mai 20 07:50 ..
  4 drwxrwsr-x  2 wouter wouter   4096 Feb 16  2012 about_files
 20 -rw-rw-r--  1 wouter wouter  18909 Feb  8  2012 about.html
 92 -rw-rw-r--  1 wouter wouter  94179 Feb 16  2012 artifacts.xml
  4 drwxrwsr-x  4 wouter wouter   4096 Feb 16  2012 configuration
  4 drwxrwsr-x  2 wouter wouter   4096 Feb 16  2012 dropins
 64 -rwxr-xr-x  1 wouter wouter  62814 Feb  8  2012 eclipse
  4 -rw-rw-r--  1 wouter wouter    408 Feb 16  2012 eclipse.ini
  4 -rw-rw-r--  1 wouter wouter     59 Feb  8  2012 .eclipseproduct
 20 -rw-rw-r--  1 wouter wouter  16536 Feb  8  2012 epl-v10.html
  4 drwxrwsr-x 38 wouter wouter   4096 Feb 16  2012 features
 12 -rw-rw-r--  1 wouter wouter   9022 Feb  8  2012 icon.xpm
260 -rwxr-xr-x  1 wouter wouter 266168 Feb  8  2012 libcairo-swt.so
 12 -rw-rw-r--  1 wouter wouter   8951 Feb  8  2012 notice.html
  4 drwxrwsr-x  5 wouter wouter   4096 Feb 16  2012 p2
 40 drwxrwsr-x 22 wouter wouter  36864 Feb 16  2012 plugins
  4 drwxrwsr-x  2 wouter wouter   4096 Feb 16  2012 readme
wouter@laptop-wouter:~/Downloads/eclipse$ ./eclipse
bash: ./eclipse: No such file or directory
wouter@laptop-wouter:~/Downloads/eclipse$ sudo ./eclipse
sudo: unable to execute ./eclipse: No such file or directory
```

Comment: 32 bit binary file won't run on 64 bit systems directly. You have to do some workarounds.

Answer (score 0):

You have to mark eclipse as an **executable** file first.

> chmod +x eclipse
>
> ./eclipse

Comment: please see the permissions of `eclipse` file.

Comment: `64 -rwxr-xr-x  1 wouter wouter  62814 Feb  8  2012 eclipse`